# why everything is reverted back in PATH env variable after reopening shell?

Tags: 13.04, environment-variables, paths

As far as I know PATH is not a temporary variable. And when you reopen your terminal it should work as before. In my case it's not.

What I do is to add another path to `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

It should append `go` dir to `PATH` variable and it does do that, but when I reopen terminal and `echo $PATH` my last appended path is cleared and I have my paths without `/usr/local/go/bin` at the end.

What is the reason this is happening? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your permanent path changes into your .profile   "reopening" is starting another terminal from scratch, and it get the PATH from the system (or your) PATH setups, not from some past session.

Comment: I put `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` in `~/.zshrc` and it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are not temporary or persistent by nature, but you can change them either temporarily or persistently. It's well explained in the tutorial [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).